# Accessibility colour changer broken after google website translator added

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-translate

I recently added the google website translator to a website, which has existing accessibility feature that changes the colour of the website via css. Everything seems to work fine on the English language but when you change the language you can no longer change the colours, apart from 2 colours on the zulu language.

Any help would be appreciated.

Below is the script for the accessibility colour changer.

```
var manual_or_random="manual" //"manual" or "random"
var randomsetting="3 days" //"eachtime", "sessiononly", or "x days (replace x with desired integer)". Only applicable if mode is random.

//////No need to edit beyond here//////////////

function getCookie(Name) { 
var re=new RegExp(Name+"=[^;]+", "i"); //construct RE to search for target name/value pair
if (document.cookie.match(re)) //if cookie found
return document.cookie.match(re)[0].split("=")[1] //return its value
return null
}

function setCookie(name, value, days) {
var expireDate = new Date()
//set "expstring" to either future or past date, to set or delete cookie, respectively
var expstring=(typeof days!="undefined")? expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate()+parseInt(days)) : expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate()-5)
document.cookie = name+"="+value+"; expires="+expireDate.toGMTString()+"; path=/";
}

function deleteCookie(name){
setCookie(name, "moot")
}


function setStylesheet(title, randomize){ //Main stylesheet switcher function. Second parameter if defined causes a random alternate stylesheet (including none) to be enabled
var i, cacheobj, altsheets=[""]
for(i=0; (cacheobj=document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {
if(cacheobj.getAttribute("rel").toLowerCase()=="alternate stylesheet" && cacheobj.getAttribute("title")) { //if this is an alternate stylesheet with title
cacheobj.disabled = true
altsheets.push(cacheobj) //store reference to alt stylesheets inside array
if(cacheobj.getAttribute("title") == title) //enable alternate stylesheet with title that matches parameter
cacheobj.disabled = false //enable chosen style sheet
}
}
if (typeof randomize!="undefined"){ //if second paramter is defined, randomly enable an alt style sheet (includes non)
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*altsheets.length)
altsheets[randomnumber].disabled=false
}
return (typeof randomize!="undefined" && altsheets[randomnumber]!="")? altsheets[randomnumber].getAttribute("title") : "" //if in "random" mode, return "title" of randomly enabled alt stylesheet
}

function chooseStyle(styletitle, days){ //Interface function to switch style sheets plus save "title" attr of selected stylesheet to cookie
if (document.getElementById){
setStylesheet(styletitle)
setCookie("mysheet", styletitle, days)
}
}

function indicateSelected(element){ //Optional function that shows which style sheet is currently selected within group of radio buttons or select menu
if (selectedtitle!=null && (element.type==undefined || element.type=="select-one")){ //if element is a radio button or select menu
var element=(element.type=="select-one") ? element.options : element
for (var i=0; i<element.length; i++){
if (element[i].value==selectedtitle){ //if match found between form element value and cookie value
if (element[i].tagName=="OPTION") //if this is a select menu
element[i].selected=true
else //else if it's a radio button
element[i].checked=true
break
}
}
}
}

if (manual_or_random=="manual"){ //IF MANUAL MODE
var selectedtitle=getCookie("mysheet")
if (document.getElementById && selectedtitle!=null) //load user chosen style sheet from cookie if there is one stored
setStylesheet(selectedtitle)
}
else if (manual_or_random=="random"){ //IF AUTO RANDOM MODE
if (randomsetting=="eachtime")
setStylesheet("", "random")
else if (randomsetting=="sessiononly"){ //if "sessiononly" setting
if (getCookie("mysheet_s")==null) //if "mysheet_s" session cookie is empty
document.cookie="mysheet_s="+setStylesheet("", "random")+"; path=/" //activate random alt stylesheet while remembering its "title" value
else
setStylesheet(getCookie("mysheet_s")) //just activate random alt stylesheet stored in cookie
}
else if (randomsetting.search(/^[1-9]+ days/i)!=-1){ //if "x days" setting
if (getCookie("mysheet_r")==null || parseInt(getCookie("mysheet_r_days"))!=parseInt(randomsetting)){ //if "mysheet_r" cookie is empty or admin has changed number of days to persist in "x days" variable
setCookie("mysheet_r", setStylesheet("", "random"), parseInt(randomsetting)) //activate random alt stylesheet while remembering its "title" value
setCookie("mysheet_r_days", randomsetting, parseInt(randomsetting)) //Also remember the number of days to persist per the "x days" variable
}
else
setStylesheet(getCookie("mysheet_r")) //just activate random alt stylesheet stored in cookie
} 
}
```

This is the html for the accessibility stylesheet changer.

```
<td width="15%" class="accessibility-colour-options"><a href="javascript:chooseStyle('none', 60)" checked="checked" title="Colour theme:default"><img src="images/accessibility/default-colours-button.gif" alt="Default theme" width="20" height="18" border="0"  /></a>

    <a href="javascript:chooseStyle('blue-theme', 60)" title="Colour theme: Dark and light blue"><img src="images/accessibility/blue-colours.gif" alt="Dark and light blue theme" width="20" height="18" border="0" /></a>

    <a href="javascript:chooseStyle('yellow-theme', 60)" title="Colour theme: Yellow and black">
    <img src="images/accessibility/yellow-colours.gif" alt="Yellow and black theme" width="20" height="18" border="0" /></a>

    <a href="javascript:chooseStyle('brown-theme', 60)" title="Colour theme: Dark blue and brown">
    <img src="images/accessibility/brown-colours.gif" alt="Dark blue and brown theme" width="18" height="18" border="0" /></a></td>


<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" title="blue-theme" href="style/blue-theme.css" />

<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" title="yellow-theme" href="style/yellow-theme.css" />

<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" title="brown-theme" href="style/brown-theme.css" />
```

This is the code that was put in for the google translator.

```
> <script type="text/javascript"
> src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>

function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
}

    <div id="google_translate_element"> </div>
```